# Akka 2.1 clustering design choices

Tags: scala, akka

I'm considering the following two approaches to set up a compute grid using Akka 2.0:

a. have a central Router node know about all Worker nodes (i.e. which host and port they are running on), keep track of their status, and assign work to them. Workers know nothing about where the central Router is, they just receive compute requests, compute results and send them back to the sender of the request.

OR

b. have a central Router node that knows nothing about where all the compute grid Workers are (i.e. which host and port they are running on). The Workers all know about the central Router, and they register themselves with the central Router when they start up. Once they register, the Router keeps track of their status (up or down), and assigns work to them.

Clearly the two approaches both have some pro's and con's that may better suit different use cases and scenarios. I'm interested about which approach the Akka community prefers given the forthcoming Akka 2.1 API? In other words, which approach is likely to be more suitable to the Clustering API that Akka 2.1 is going to provide?

I looked through the Akka 2.0 RC2 documentation which does discuss briefly the Clustering features that will arrive in Akka 2.1, but there are not too many specifics released yet. I'm hoping to get better insights from the Akka experts in the community.

Comment: Why a central node at all? It's just a role right?